# Proof $ \cosh x=1 \Leftrightarrow x=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, hyperbolic-functions

I just calculated the function value in $x=0$. Is that ok? If not, what am I suppose to do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have proved that$$x=0\implies\cosh(x)=1.$$It remains to prove that$$\cosh(x)=1\implies x=0.$$In order to do that, use the fact that\begin{align}\cosh(x)=1&\iff e^x+e^{-x}=2\\&\iff e^{-x}(e^x-1)^2=0.\end{align}

Comment: oh, I think I understand what I'm suppose to do.

Comment: I got $e^x+e^{-x}=2\iff(1-e^x)(1-e^{-x})=0$.  The solution ends up being the same, but I don't see how you got   $e^x+e^{-x}=2\iff e^{-x}(e^x-1)=0$

Comment: It was a typo. I meant $e^{-x}(e^x-1)^{\color{red}{2}}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Showing that $\cosh 0=1$ is one direction of the $\iff$ arrow. The other direction amounts to showing this:

> No other real number $x$ has $\cosh x=1$.

There are several approaches to solve this, most conventionally through derivatives or the geometric definition of $\cosh$.

Comment: only the geometric definition of cosh is allowed.

Comment: @Xenusi Well, proving that no point of the right branch of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ has $x=1$ other than $(1,0)$ should do it then.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To prove $$\cosh x=1\iff x=0$$ is like to prove$$\exp x=1\iff x=0$$

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not enough. I suggest the AM-GM inequality. since $\cosh x$ is the arithmetic mean of $e^{\pm x}$, whose geometric mean is $1$, it's $\ge1$ with equality iff $e^x=e^{-x}$, which is equivalent to $e^x=1$, or to $x=0$.

Comment: you can do $\cosh(x)=1\implies\sinh(x)^2=\cosh(x)^2-1=0\implies e^x=e^{-x}$ as well.

Comment: @zwim Your comment should be an answer.